# Is it possible to fetch 'only iOS' or only 'Android' apps from Flurry reporting API?

Tags: flurry, flurry-analytics

I use 'https://api-metrics.flurry.com/public/v1/dimensions/app/values' endpoint to get all the apps. But I want to fetch 'only iOS' or only 'Android apps'. Is there a way to filter it?

```
{
  "dimensions": [
    {
      "id": "1290607",
      "name": "EasyScripts",
      "company|id": "358140",
      "platform|id": "2",
      "apiKey": "YJ4SH8289GWV7XQDMSYY",
      "deleted": "0",
      "platform|name": "iPhone"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the response, but 'platform|name' key is not iOS or Android; it is 'iPhone'. Is there a way to filter this response according to my needs? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get ‘only IOS’: you could use: [https://api-metrics.flurry.com/public/v1/dimensions/app/values?filters=app%7Cplatform%7Cname-in["iPhone"](https://api-metrics.flurry.com/public/v1/dimensions/app/values?filters=app%7Cplatform%7Cname-in%5B%22iPhone%22), "iPad"]

to get ‘only Android’ you could use [https://api-metrics.flurry.com/public/v1/dimensions/app/values?filters=app%7Cplatform%7Cname-eq["Android"]](https://api-metrics.flurry.com/public/v1/dimensions/app/values?filters=app%7Cplatform%7Cname-eq%5B%22Android%22%5D)